# What is a "solar ready" electrical panel and how does it save money in a solar installation?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I see these listed as a seperate category "Meter Mains - Solar Ready" at my supply house. Eaton MBE2040PV200BTS is an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> “Solar Ready” devices route the alternate power to the supply side of
> the service disconnecting means and provide terminations to the load
> side of the meter socket. This eliminates having a common bus and
> therefore the need to de-rate the main breaker.
>
> https://www.downloads.siemens.com/download-center/d/SIE_BR_SolarSolutions.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you Google the part #, you can find the Eaton page with the link to the full details PDF which includes [this link to the Eaton Solar Power Centers PDF](https://www.eaton.com/ecm/idcplg?IdcService=GET_FILE&allowInterrupt=1&RevisionSelectionMethod=LatestReleased&noSaveAs=0&Rendition=Primary&dDocName=BR003002EN)

Main description from the PDF:

> Eaton’s solar power centers combine both utility power and solar photovoltaic (PV) power into one enclosure. Solar power centers can be applied as a component of a complete PV electrical system. Eaton offers the industry’s most complete line of balance of system (BOS) products, along with a wide variety of configurations, including loadcenters and meter breakers.
>
> The solar power centers feature industry-exclusive, factory-installed permanent arkings, which help to ensure National Electrical Code® (NEC®) compliance. Required
>   by the NEC, these markings enable quick and easy identification of product ratings and location of the parallel energy source disconnect. Prior to installation, contact your
>   local utility to confirm approval.

Basically, it is a box designed to connect to both utility & solar (or other locally generated power) with appropriate markings to make it clear, as required by code, that it is a dual power source system.